# How to select/Deselect all checkboxes in oracle apex form

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex-19.1

[image]
I have a page region in Oracle Apex, that contains many checkboxes (apex form).
I want a functionality to add a checkbox at the header of every checkbox item, that will Select/Deselect all the checkbox items underneath.

I am new to Apex development, and need help on this.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE and then images as support, but not JUST images. If the Oracle output is plain HTML, we do not need to know about oracle

Comment: Is the text above the checkbox groups from each item's label or are you using sub-regions for that? The solution will be highly dependent on the HTML markup, so it would be helpful if you could put an example on apex.oracle.com. It doesn't need to be the actual app if you can reproduce it accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that assumes the text above the checkboxes is from the item's label (somehow I don't think that's the case). If needed, I can update the answer to better fit your page when I know more about it.

First, go into each checkbox where you want to add this "toggle" functionality. Scroll down to the **CSS Classes** attribute and put **toggle-cb** in the field.

Next, go to the page level attributes and add the following code to the **Function and Global Variable Declaration** attribute:

```
function enableToggle() {
  var $wrapperDiv = $(this);
  var $label = $wrapperDiv.find('.t-Form-label');
  var $item = $wrapperDiv.find('.apex-item-checkbox');
  var buttonHtml = '<button type="button" class="t-Button t-Button--tiny t-Button--simple">Toggle all</button>';

  $label.html($label.text() + ' ' + buttonHtml);

  $label.find('button').on('click', function(event) {
    var $button = $(this);
    var $checkboxes = $item.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checkedCount = $checkboxes.filter(function() {
      return this.checked === true;
    }).length;
    var check = checkedCount < $checkboxes.length;

    $checkboxes.each(function() {
      this.checked = check;
    });

    event.stopPropagation();
    $button.blur();
  });
}
```

Finally, add the following code to the **Execute when Page Loads** attribute of the page:

```
$('.toggle-cb').each(enableToggle);
```

This will add a button to each item's label (provided the checkbox has the toggle-cb class) that does the toggle:

[image]

See the following to learn more about the code used above:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pjur4Zkkwsk&list=PLUo-NIMouZ_sgdQpMbXXwhHKpwRggCY34&index=1

Comment: If the checkbox label is blank, and we have a sub region label that is displayed, what changes would i need to make.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case (I couldn't get my checkboxes to look like yours). Honestly, I can't say exactly without seeing the exact markup. If you put an example on apex.oracle.com that mimics your page, that could work. Alternatively, we could meet online. If you'd rather do that, just DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/).

Comment: @DanMcGhan this works perfectly but I noticed if I have the attribute "Appearance->Template->Required" the label adds a "(Value Required)" right before the toggle all button.  I guess it has to do with the label including that. Do you have any ideas on how to prevent the "(Value Required)" extra text?  - Thanks for posting this really-really cool answer.